# Console: Can't type special characters (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, console, keyboard-layout

We have linux-based computers (Ubuntu 14.04.4) prepared by other company to use their software. We have root password.
Those computers has no X Window System. Just consoles.

There is a problem with keyboard settings. I can't type several special characters: >?:"{}_+@#$%^&*(
When I'm pressing `Shift+.` it should result with `>` letter but it still makes `.` (dot).
When I'm pressing `Shift+;` it should result with `:` (colon) letter but it still makes `;` (semicolon), etc.

What could cause that problem?
Where can I fix this?

Tom

Comment: That sounds like a broken keyboard to me... The "special" characters you listed are actually not special at all.

Comment: run `showkey` and see if when you press `shift` it sees any events.

Comment: An aside, if you are using just the console, then you could login via `ssh`, or `putty` (if using Microsoft's Windows).

Comment: Also asked on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789223/

Comment: How many shift keys do you have? Have you tried them both? I've noticed although most keyboards have two of the same keys (e.g. `shift`, `ctrl`, `alt`) on some systems one of the two is disabled. These are *necessary* characters, not *special* characters.

Comment: OP: Thank you for responds. I did'n know how to call that keys ;)
Kayboard is fine. It works on other computers. I tried also older (ps/2) keyboard with the same result.
I tried left Shift and right Shift. I tried also tty1, tty2, tty3,... all react the same.
Showkey command can see left Shift and right Shift, and reacts with other keys.

Comment: OP: A strange thing is `Shift+,` works and makes `<` character, but `Shift+.` doesn't work (makes `.` char)

Comment: if you run `dumpkeys` into a file you should see how keycodes like 51 are translated into symbols (names for chars), like `comma` and `less`. For 52 it should be `period` and `greater`.  The first 2 columns are for unshifted and shifted.

Comment: OP: OK, I barely managed to run `dumpkeys` into a file because I can't type `>` (I made *.sh file and I lunched it)

I share a file with this link:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/rg60k56k2ev0acj/dumpkeys_all.txt

Comment: So if you look at the line for keycode 52 it has `keycode  52 = period`, ie there is no 2nd symbol.  You can see `keycode  86` has `less greater`. This key is probably at the bottom left of the keyboard, so the layout does not correspond to your keyboard. You need to find a correct keymap file on your system (or even install it), and run `loadkeys` to replace the current console mapping.  A quick search for answers for "ubuntu loadkeys" says you should try: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: Sounds like an incorrect keyboard layout/language setup to me. Have you checked your keyboard settings to see what layout is applied?